# Local history in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I saw local history in eclipse.But it is giving the data for me for approximately 3 to 4 days.

I have following questions:

1) At what time (or basing on which)it will save to local history.

2) How i can get the previous history before what this is showing.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse

```
Window ->Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History
```

You will have to increase the "Days to keep files" property.

Comment: At what time (or basing on which)it will save to local history.

Comment: "Every time an editable file is saved in the Workbench, the Workbench updates the local history of that file and logs the changes that have been made." [Source](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm)

Answer (score 1):

**Use a version control system** in addition to local history. Local history is mostly meant to help you in undoing some bad editing changes, not for managing versions over days or even weeks.

To get back to a version from last week, you really should have explicitly created a "known good" version last week, using a version control system. Local history also will not tell you that you modified another dependent file at the same time.

The initial effort of learning a version control system like [git](/questions/tagged/git) or [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) is nothing compared to the safety from being able to restore each piece of the history of your software.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone also faces this issue.

Recently I was changing some preferences to speed up Eclipse (from some article on the Internet), and after that the "Compare With..." option and "Replace With > Local History" have completely disappeared from file's context menu. Even the "History" view was missing in Open View dialog. At the same time, in newly created workspaces the Local History functionality was still available.

After some research, I found that this happens when we disable **Preferences > Global > Capabilities > Team** option.

After enabling the **"Core Team Support"** option and restarting Eclipse, the Local History was back.